# Alternative for Adobe Flash Player

Tags: software-development, flash

Which software can act as a good alternative for Adobe Flash Player?

It should be smooth and fast like flash player.

Comment: See also: [Flash player that doesn't try to sneak in extra software](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/32/60)

Comment: Do you want something that plays flash files that isn't from Adobe? But you tagged it as `software-development`, so are you asking for something that authors flash files, or an alternative to the flash platform altogether?

Answer (score 2):

Major sites such as YouTube has switched over to using HTML5 for Videos, so any browser will support Videos without the need for Flash or a replacement. The standards for this practice is on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp). Also, there is mobile support with this method also.

**EDIT 1**

Sorry, but there is more details within [HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/) for compatibility, how to actually add video into HTML code, and different important options for it also.

Comment: The standard (= specification) is not on W3Schools (which has no relation with W3C), but on W3C’s [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/embedded-content-0.html#the-video-element)([.1](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content.html#the-video-element)) resp. WHATWG’s [HTML](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#the-video-element).